# Real numbers determine rational numbers

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, algebra-precalculus

Determine the rational numbers $x,y$ ,knowing that $x(1+\sqrt2)^2$ + $y(1-\sqrt2) = 1 $

My result is $3x$ + $y$ - $y\sqrt2$ = $1$

I'm not sure how to continue this.

Comment: You forgot $+2\sqrt{2}x$. That would mean that $2x - y = 0$ and $3x+y = 1$. Can you continue from here?

Comment: Another approach would be to multiply everything by $1+\sqrt 2$ and see what shakes out...

Comment: $x(1+\sqrt{x})^2 = x(1+2\sqrt{2} + 2) = x(3+2\sqrt{2}) = 3x + 2\sqrt{2}x$. Analogously, $y(1-\sqrt{2}) = 1 - \sqrt{2}y$. So if you add up both you get $(3x-y) + (2x-y)\sqrt{2}$.

Comment: I solved the system . I didn't understand your result , maybe because i'm stupid , but i want to learn. So i started to solve it again and i'm on this $3x$ + $2x\sqrt2$ + $y$ - $y\sqrt2$.How did you get that form : +$2\sqrt2x$?

Answer (score 1):

We have

$$3x+2\sqrt2x+y-\sqrt2y=1\iff\begin{cases}3x+y=1\\{}\\2\sqrt2x-\sqrt2y=0\end{cases}$$

Take it from here now.

Answer (score 1):

As usual with equations, assume you *know* rational $x$ and $y$ such that the equality holds.

Developing the square and rearranging terms you have
$$
x+2x+y-1=(y-2x)\sqrt{2}
$$
If $y-x\ne0$, this could be rewritten
$$
\sqrt{2}=\frac{3x+y-1}{y-2x}
$$
but this would imply $\sqrt{2}$ is rational. Since this is not the case, you must have $y-2x=0$ and so also $3x+y-1=0$.

This easily implies $x=1/5$, $y=2/5$ and it's also easy to check the equality actually holds.

Of course, knowing a bit more about algebraic numbers makes the argument easier.

Comment: Looks like there's a slight error, I believe your RHS $2(y-x)\sqrt 2$ should be $(y-2x)\sqrt 2$...

Comment: @abiessu Yes, you're right.

Answer (score 0):

Using another approach, we have

$$x(1+\sqrt 2)^2+y(1-\sqrt 2)=1\\
x(1+\sqrt 2)^3+y(1-2)=1+\sqrt 2$$

This isolates $x$ as associated with all terms having $\sqrt 2$, yielding

$$x+3x\sqrt 2+6x+2x\sqrt 2-y = 1+\sqrt 2\\
7x-y=1, 5x\sqrt 2=\sqrt 2$$

Then we immediately see $x=\frac 15$ and can easily get $y=\frac 25$.